# Django Cookie Detection Fails Though Cookie Hasn't Expired

Tags: python, django, session, cookies

I have a cookie on the client browser to store a hash value. I've extended the cookie lifetime  using this

```
response.set_cookie('kmliCookie', randomHash, settings.COOKIE_LIFETIME)
```

and firefox shows that this cookie expired next month.

When I refresh the page, django detects the cookie even if I close the browser and come back the cookie is detected but after a system restart (may be due to IP change) the cookie is not detected.

Its not even there in the request object. But firefox still has the cookie and it's not expired.

I use this code to detect the cookie

```
if request.COOKIES.get('kmliCookie'):
    message = "valid"
else:
    message = "invalid"
```

it results in invalid (only after system restart or ip change).

I used this to check the request object.

```
  render(request, 'index.html', {'request':request.COOKIE})
```

and request object didn't have kmliCookie.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you accessing the page?  Are you using `localhost:port` or are you using the (changing) IP address?

Comment: I'm running the server at port 80, so i'm accessing it at localhost/

Comment: Hmm... you say firefox still has the cookie - does it tie that cookie to `localhost` or a specific IP address?

Comment: yes, it is tied to localhost

Comment: What happens if you try this using `127.0.0.1` as the address (before and after a reset) instead?

Comment: Same, cookie is not found in the request object.